# MSSQL Inner Join on Concatenated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm not a DBA so please don't yell at me. Trying to do an inner join and Group By using a concatenated column. The ON statement is producing a syntax error. I do not have access to the original tables and am trying to normalize this into another table, I know its ugly. Not overly worried about performance, just need to work. Cant use functions either.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[carrier_code],[carrier_name], [carrier_grouping], A.[collector_name], [dataset_loaded], [docnum], [envoy_payer_id], [loc], [market], [master_payor_grouping], [plan_class], [plan_name], A.[resp_ins],A.[resp_ind], A.[resp_payor_grouping], A.[Resp_Plan_Type], A.[rspphone], A.[state], A.[sys],A.[resp_ins]+A.[resp_payor_grouping]+A.[carrier_code]+A.[state]+A.[Collector_Name] as ExtId
    FROM [Table1] A
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  [resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name] as Extid
    FROM [Table1]
    WHERE [resp_ind] = 'Insurance'
    GROUP BY [resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name]) B
    ON A.[resp_ins]+A.[resp_payor_grouping]+A.[carrier_code]+A.[state]+A.[Collector_Name] = B.[resp_ins]+B.[resp_payor_grouping]+B.[carrier_code]+B.[state]+B.[Collector_Name];
```

My ON and Group By statements are eventually the primary key in new table.

Comment: `Not working` is not helping. So what's going wrong ? No result ? Error ? Something weird ?

Answer (score 0):

Your alias `B` hasn't columns as you mentioned. It has just on column `Extid`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[carrier_code],[carrier_name], [carrier_grouping], A.[collector_name], [dataset_loaded], [docnum], [envoy_payer_id], [loc], [market], [master_payor_grouping], [plan_class], [plan_name], A.[resp_ins],A.[resp_ind], A.[resp_payor_grouping], A.[Resp_Plan_Type], A.[rspphone], A.[state], A.[sys],A.[resp_ins]+A.[resp_payor_grouping]+A.[carrier_code]+A.[state]+A.[Collector_Name] as ExtId
    FROM [Table1] A
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  [resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name] as Extid
    FROM [Table1]
    WHERE [resp_ind] = 'Insurance'
    GROUP BY [resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name]) B
    ON A.[resp_ins]+A.[resp_payor_grouping]+A.[carrier_code]+A.[state]+A.[Collector_Name] = B.Extid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I didn't put all the column in result, you can manage yourself.

```
select A.*
    from
    (
        select [carrier_code],[carrier_name], [sys],[resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name] as ExtId
        FROM [Table1]
    ) A
    inner join
    (
        select distinct Extid
        from
        (
            SELECT  [resp_ins]+[resp_payor_grouping]+[carrier_code]+[state]+[Collector_Name] as ExtId
            FROM [Table1]
            WHERE [resp_ind] = 'Insurance'
        ) ins
    ) B on (A.ExtId = B.ExtId)
```

Comment: This ran and pretty quickly but maybe my logic was missing something. Got the # of inserts I expected but also many duplicate key errors. I was trying to eliminate those with the Group By for the ExtId. It's working as expected when using MySQL but converting it is causing me these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate the values - you can `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` on multiple columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM 
    [Table1] A
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [resp_ins],
            [resp_payor_grouping],
            [carrier_code],
            [state],
            [Collector_Name]
        FROM 
            [Table1]
        WHERE 
            [resp_ind] = 'Insurance'
        GROUP BY 
            [resp_ins],
            [resp_payor_grouping],
            [carrier_code],
            [state],
            [Collector_Name]
    ) B
    ON 
    (
        A.[resp_ins] = B.[resp_ins] 
    Or 
        (A.[resp_ins] Is Null And B.[resp_ins] Is Null)
    )
    And 
    (
        A.[resp_payor_grouping] = B.[resp_payor_grouping] 
    Or 
        (A.[resp_payor_grouping] Is Null And B.[resp_payor_grouping] Is Null)
    )
    And 
    (
        A.[carrier_code] = B.[carrier_code] 
    Or 
        (A.[carrier_code] Is Null And B.[carrier_code] Is Null)
    )
    And 
    (
        A.[state] = B.[state] 
    Or 
        (A.[state] Is Null And B.[state] Is Null)
    )
    And 
    (
        A.[Collector_Name] = B.[Collector_Name] 
    Or 
        (A.[Collector_Name] Is Null And B.[Collector_Name] Is Null)
    )
;
```

Comment: I think one of the issues with this approach is that some of the values are null. So needed to group by the concatenation of all of them at once to avoid that.

Comment: @user2451: If some of the values are `Null`, then concatenating them won't work unless you have the `Concat Null Yields Null` option turned off. Grouping by a column containing `Null` will work; the only issue will be the conditions on the `Join`.

Comment: @user2451: I've updated the `Join` conditions in my answer to allow for `Null` values.